# VBA Combine values in 2 userform textboxes into a third textbox

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

I am having difficulty getting the value from textbox 1 and textbox 2 to combine and display in a textbox3 on a userform. Textbox1 and Textbox2 are locked, the values are dynamic and auto-filled from radio button controls. I have tried the following but it doesn't display the combined result in textbox3 and I think it's because the values in textbox 1 & 2 are the result of counter controls on the radio buttons. See image link.

```
Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
    textbox3.text=Textbox1.text & Textbox2.text
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to set the value of textbox3 within a TextBox3_Change event procedure.

Comment: to follow what Jeeped said above, could you put this code in another method, such as whenever textbox1 or 2 is changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the code below works best, your values will be combined. I placed a space between the values for s&g's.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    Me.TextBox3.Value = Me.TextBox1.Value & " " + Me.TextBox2.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked! Can you help me understand why using textbox 2_change worked while textbox3_change did not?

Comment: Because you are putting the values from TextBox 1 and 2 into TextBox 3. TextBox 3 does not change until the values are transferred there, the only way to get them to there is when you update either of the other two TextBoxes.

Comment: Ahhh I see! Thank you for taking the time to explain the logic to me. :)

Comment: I am glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to code below:

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
   TextBox3.Value = TextBox1.text & TextBox2.text
End Sub
```

Hope that helps!